# PyInstallerにおいて管理者権限で実行するEXEの作成方法

Tags: python

PyInstallerを使用してスタンドアロンなWindowsアプリを作成しています。
作成したEXEファイルをInnoSetupにて、ProgramFilesフォルダにインストールして実行させたいと考えております。
アプリケーションは、直下のフォルダにLogファイルを生成するため、作成したEXEファイルに管理者権限で実行する設定が必要です。
PyInstallerでEXE構築時に管理者権限を付与するようにできるのでしょうか？

Comment: アプリケーションの設計を改めるべきと思います。

Comment: それに関してこんな議論の記事があります。[Where to store an application log file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1572934/9014308) そうは言ってもという場合のオプションはこちらの`--uac-admin`あたりだと思われます。[Windows specific options](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-specific-options)

Comment: ありがとうございます。--uac-adminにたどり着きました。このオプションをSPECファイルに記述する方法を探しています。ご指摘の通り、確かに冷静に考えるとLog等の出力先を見直すべきですね。

Comment: Undocumentedですかね、`EXE()`の中に`uac_admin=True`のようです。ただし`onefile`と同時だと上手く行かないかもしれません。[UAC not working in onefile again, migrate old UAC test #1729](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1729), [PyInstaller UAC not working in onefile mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43068920/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。UACオプションの有無に限らず、onefileオプションに相当する設定はうまく動作していません。PuInstallerのIssueでも未解決状態のようです。